# Failed to load images and plugins on Web Server

Tags: html, css, plugins, webserver

I just uploaded my files onto my Webserver via Filezilla and my plugins and images are not loading.
I have a seperate plugins and images folder (I'll add a screenshot)

This is my file path:

```
<a href="index"><img src="/images/logo-transparent.png" alt=""></a>
```

[image: Here are my files]

Console is giving out this error:

*GET http://www.WEBSITENAME.de/images/logo-transparent.png 404 (Not Found)*

Comment: When you open the URL (http://www.WEBSITENAME.de/images/logo-transparent.png) in the browser, are you able to see the image?

Comment: Which web server you are using?

Comment: @GokulaKannanT No i can't see it

Comment: So the webserver might not be serving the image.

Comment: What would you suggest? @GokulaKannanT

Comment: We can not do anything from the frontend side. The server should serve static files like images. Then only we can get it. Can I know what server you are using?

Comment: I'll contact my Hosting Provider and ask their tech support.

Comment: Your folder is named `Images`, not `images`. Linux-based servers have case-sensitive file systems.

Comment: ill try to change that @04FS